# In C++ how could I cast a sub class instance from one base class pointer to another without dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, types, casting

I want to do this without `dynamic_cast`:

```
class A {};
class B {};
class C : public A, public B {};

void func()
{
    A* pClassA = new C();
    B* pClassB = what_cast<B*>(pClassA); // what could the cast be?
}
```

I think the instance of type `ClassC` could represent as both `ClassA` and `ClassB`. Now if I could only get the pointer in the type of `ClassA` how can I cast it into `ClassB` without `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: Have you looked at `LLVM::dyn_cast<>` - it does require a bit of work, but supports dynamic casting without names.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Actually I'm going to do the similar things in my code. I have get the problem when cast between unrelated classes. I can tell if a `A*` pointed object is also `B` or not, with some virtual functions, but I don't know how to `cast` it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In well designed code, this type of problem should hardly ever occur. So, better rethink your design. Perhaps you want to avoid polymorphism, when you really should use it? You could

```
struct B; // forward decl
struct A {
  virtual B*this_as_B_ptr() { return nullptr; }
  const B*this_as_B_ptr() const { return const_cast<A*>(this)->this_as_B_ptr(); }
  virtual~A() {}
};
struct B { /* ... */ }; // may be in different header
struct C:A,B            // may be in yet different header
{
  B*this_as_B_ptr() override { return this; }
};

A* pA = new C;
B* pB = pA->this_as_B_ptr();
```

-- effectively implementing a more efficient way of dynamic cast.

Comment: So the key is to make `C` hold the both pointer to `A` and `B` internally?

Comment: @jayatubi `C` *is* both an `A` and `B`, so it doesn't need to *hold* any pointers, it simply returns `this`. The key is that only `C` can do that, but not `A` as it is not a `B`. The polymorphic solution in my answer requires no additional data members, only the virtual table that any polymorphic types has.

Answer (score 5):

`A` and `B` are unrelated types, so you can't just cast between them. So long as you are *certain* that `pClassA` points to a `C`, you can do an intermediate cast to `C*`, then rely on implicit derived-to-base conversions to get to `B*`:

```
B* pClassB = static_cast<C*>(pClassA);
```

Or you can explicitly cast through `C*` to `B*`:

```
B* pClassB = static_cast<B*>(static_cast<C*>(pClassA));
```

Comment: So for the cast I `have to` provide an intermediate class, such as C in this case, right?

Comment: @jayatubi Well if you don't have an intermediate class, the cast doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some casts to cast `pClassA` into `B*`, including `reinterpret_cast` and C-style casts.

Your real question is "How can I cast it *safely* without `dynamic_cast`. Well, although you can do all kind of object-validation mechanisms, I doubt that you really need them.

what is wrong with `dynamic_cast`?

***Edit:***
hmmm. I prefer Idiomatic C++ over tricks but there are times where you do need the raw size/speed. I would go with some marking mechanism:

```
enum Types{AType,BType,CType};

struct A {
    int type;

A(): type(AType) {}
bool is (Types wantedType) {return (type & wantedType) == wantedType; }

};

struct B {

};

struct C : public A, public B {
    C(){ type = (type | CType) | BType ; }
};
```

this way you statically ask if the object is from the type `Types`

real run:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1774f9c85603fa31

Comment: For `dynamic_cast` the compiler will generate the full name of all the classes in the final binary which is what I want to strip out.

Comment: What is wrong with `dynamic_cast`? 1. It requires the classes to be polymorphic; 2. It has a non-trivial runtime cost attached.

Comment: @Angew 1. Reduce the size of binary; 2. Hide my class names which I do want them to be exposed

Comment: You must have really tight size constraints :p I've never heard anyone avoiding dynamic_cast because of binary size. When it comes to exposed class names, I would rather use some tool to obfuscate the code.

Comment: @DavidHaim what is your edit code trying to achieve? That just reports the static type, which you have already.

Comment: *Any type of cast?* Nope, you **cannot `static_cast`** between unrelated types.

Comment: @Walter changed it to "Some casts"

Comment: @TartanLlama we're imitating the VTable on run time. each constructor is updating the type accordingly so you can query the type on runtime.

Comment: One issue with this type of design is that the programmer of any derived class of `A` must explicitly give the correct `type` argument to the constructyor of `A` -- it's not automatic and hence easily forgotten/lost in refactoring: an error-prone design.

Comment: @Walter  of course. when you re-implemnting already existing functionality you go on re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @DavidHaim I can tell about the `is` and now I could know the `A*` points to a `C` object is also a type of `B` with virtual functions. But how can I cast the `A*` to `B*` without an intermediate type `C`?

Comment: you can't. A does not share any link with B. a tank may inherit from weapon and a vehicle, because a tank is a vehical and also a weapon. but you can't turn your Toyota car to a shot-gun.